# How do disable a Swap partition to use Free space?

Tags: partitioning, swap

Hello I'm new at using Ubuntu. I'm using a Virtual box to run Ubuntu but I ran out of storage space so I added more storage to the Virtual box.

My issue here is that I cannot allocate the unallocated space to my Filesystem partition. From what I read is because I have a "Swap partition 2" between the Filesystem and the Free Space partitions.

I have read about using:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
```

But it says it cannot find the file. I also read that it may be dangerous to remove the partition so I wanted to know what's the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: Use `sudo swapoff -a` to disable all swaps, even if it is a partition.  `/swapfile` is a file and not a partition.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345916/edit) and show me a screenshot of `gparted` when looking at your disk, and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thank you this worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a  swap partition it is not called /swapfile.
Run the command `swapon` to see the ame of the sawp-partition.

Then run `sudo swapoff /dev/sdxx` where /dev/sdxx is the result from the command above.

You can then go on deleting the swap partition and expand your disk space.

You might also want to create a new swap space. You can look up how to create a swapfile. And remember to update /etc/fstab with the new swap information.

Comment: Your answer lacks specific detail on how to do what you suggest.

Comment: @heynnema it should be enough to get OP over the point he was stranded on ...

Comment: OP says *"Swap partition 2"*, which suggests either LVM, or multiple swap partitions. Without asking the OP questions, you don't know what the configuration is, so it may not be as simple as you begin to suggest... esp for a new OP.

Comment: @heynnema in my world it indicates that partition 1 is the os partition he tries to expand, and partition 2 is the one bnlocking for him to expand into the newly added space, eh. like /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2. Anyway, the output of `swapon` will tell name(s) and number of swap spaces,